# Rshiny doesn't allow more than 2 Sidebar panel

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create shiny app that creates several lists from which the user can select elements by ticking boxes, then download a csv file for each set. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Select Elements"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("elements1", "Select Elements Set 1:",
                         choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                         selected = NULL),
      br(),
      downloadButton("downloadCSV1", "Download Elements Set 1")
    ),
    
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("elements2", "Select Elements Set 2:",
                         choices = c("G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"),
                         selected = NULL),
      br(),
      downloadButton("downloadCSV2", "Download Elements Set 2")
    ),
    
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("elements3", "Select Elements Set 3:",
                         choices = c("M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R"),
                         selected = NULL),
      br(),
      downloadButton("downloadCSV3", "Download Elements Set 3")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Function to create CSV for Set 1
  output$downloadCSV1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("selected_elements_set1.csv", sep = "")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      # Create data frame with selected elements
      selected_df <- data.frame(Selected_Element = input$elements1)
      
      # Write CSV
      write.csv(selected_df, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  # Function to create CSV for Set 2
  output$downloadCSV2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("selected_elements_set2.csv", sep = "")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      # Create data frame with selected elements
      selected_df <- data.frame(Selected_Element = input$elements2)
      
      # Write CSV
      write.csv(selected_df, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  # Function to create CSV for Set 3
  output$downloadCSV3 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("selected_elements_set3.csv", sep = "")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      # Create data frame with selected elements
      selected_df <- data.frame(Selected_Element = input$elements3)
      
      # Write CSV
      write.csv(selected_df, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code work perfectly fine for two set of elements, but once I add a third element and try to run the fluidPage(), I encounter the following error:

`Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector`

What is the source of this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider `shinydashboard` where you can put each of your sidebarpanel items in a menuItem on the sidebar.  Each menuItem can have multiple menuItem/ submenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

The `sidebarLayout` function has the following arguments:

```r
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel,
  mainPanel,
  position = c("left", "right"),
  fluid = TRUE
)
```

So if you feed it with three arguments, the third one is the `position` argument, which cannot be a `sidebarPanel`.

If you want three "sidebars" side-by-side, you can try:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 4,
      ......
    ),
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 4,
      ......
    ),
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 4,
      ......
    )
  )
)
```